# How can i edit this line to don't be a warning aymore

Tags: c++, warnings

The following line gives me a warning:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SpamBannListArray.size(); i++)
```

> ```
> char.cpp: In member function 'bool CHARACTER::SpamListCheck(const char*)':
> char.cpp:7280: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
> ```

What do I need to change in order to get rid of the warning above?

Comment: Unrelated: if `SpamBannListArray` is a library container, odds are pretty good that you can use a range-based for loop: `for (const auto & spamban: SpamBannListArray)` and eliminate a bunch of code.

Comment: Btw, *for range* is probably sufficient: `for (/*const*/ auto& e : SpamBannListArray)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `unsigned` type for the declaration of `i` in the `for()` loop header, since `SpamBannListArray.size()` most probably returns an `unsigned` type:

```
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SpamBannListArray.size(); i++)
   // ^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < SpamBannListArray.size(); i++)
```

Otherwise your code might be prone for `signed` value overflows / wraparounds when hitting negative values.

---

As pointed out in comments using a range based `for()` loop, without need to specify an indexing variable should be preferred with the current c++ standard:

```
for (auto item : SpamBannListArray) {
    // Do something with item
}
```

In case you need to manipulate items inplace, use `auto &`.

Comment: You can also use auto to declare the loop variable

Comment: @kirikoumath Not with that literal `0` actually. You have to write at least to write `auto i = 0u`

Comment: `size_t` is the more correct form. Leave the data model up to the implementation.

Comment: Of course, you’re correct. And indeed size_t is best option

Comment: @CinderBiscuits Depends what `SpamBannListArray` is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The line comes from an open source game engine: https://github.com/nikita322/vanillacore_llvm6/blob/c2b10f6813f2999e397b0c05dbc4233863ac250f/vanilla/source/game/src/char.cpp `std::list<std::string>`

Comment: @CinderBiscuits It doesn't though does it because that line already has `unsigned int i`. Anyway, with the suggestion as you've phrased it, I think it would be safer if it clarified that it is contingent on the RHS operand also being a `size_t`, which may well be (probably is) the case here but isn't necessarily in general, and the question doesn't ask about a specific library. Ta

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does though because that particular repo as stated in the description as updated for LLVM6, but to humor you, we will travel back in time to the original patches posted to a forum for the game: https://metin2dev.org/board/index.php?/topic/169-cadvanced-chat-spam-protection/

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I think you're missing my point, which is that unless the advice is clearly targeted at that specific library's code, or more generally attached to a disclaimer that it only applies when `.size()` returns a `size_t`, it's a false generalisation.

Comment: Well given we can deduce with almost guaranteed certainty the source of this line, by the unique spelling of the member name, by the line number, by the asker's history of asking questions about game programming, a disclaimer that some code doesn't conform to STL guidelines isn't necessary. You now know the context of the line and that the RHS evaluates to `size_t`. There's no need to generalize it.